# what is the difference between payment gateway and marchant gateway?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, gateway

what is the difference between payment gateway and marchant gateway?

Which one should be used when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much difference, but if you think about the big ones in terms like Sazzad said:

Payment Gateway = PayPal

You redirect the user to PayPal's page and they handle the transaction.  You can do it on your site, but you need an iframe, so ultimately it is still using their site to handle the transaction.  Payment Gateways like PayPal are usually higher percentage rates.  The credit card company gives the money to PayPal and then PayPal gives the money to the merchant.  The user will usually see PayPal on their credit card statement.

Merchant Gateway = Authorize.net

The user puts CC info in on your site, you send the data via an API, and the data is then sent and you get paid.  Merchant gateways usually have lower charge rates.  Money goes straight from the credit card to you, not really using as much of a middle man as a payment gateway does.  The user will see your company on their credit card statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to redirect user to external gateway page to pay, then its Payment Gateway.

If you need to use stored credit card, and your client will not leave your website to pay, then its Merchant Gateway.